# Passing logged in user to form

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I am trying to pass logged in user to form that i would like to save.

forms.py

```
class SpotForm(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SpotForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['gross_weight'].widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min':0})
    self.fields['volume'].widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'min': 0})

class Meta:
    model = Spot
    fields = [
        'gross_weight','volume','origin_country','origin_port',
        'dest_country','dest_port','ship_week','requestor'
              ]
```

models.py

```
class Stakeholder(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
mail = models.CharField(max_length=40)

def __str__(self):
    return self.mail
class Spot(models.Model):
STATUSES = (
    ('Open','Open'),
    ('Closed','Closed')
)
gross_weight = models.FloatField(null=False,default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
volume = models.FloatField(null=False,default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
origin_country = models.CharField(
    validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[A-Z]{2}', message='Country code is two letters')], max_length=2,null=True)
origin_port = models.CharField(
    validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[A-Z]{3}', message='Port code is three letters')], max_length=3,null=True)
dest_country = models.CharField(
    validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[A-Z]{2}', message='Country code is two letters')], max_length=2,null=True)
dest_port = models.CharField(
    validators=[RegexValidator(regex='[A-Z]{3}', message='Port code is three letters')], max_length=3,null=True)
time_registered = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
spot_status = models.CharField(max_length=6,default='Open', choices=STATUSES)
ship_week = models.CharField(max_length=2,null=True)
requestor = models.ForeignKey(Stakeholder,null = True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.origin_country + self.origin_port + '-' + self.dest_country +self.dest_port + '-' + self.ship_week
```

views.py

```
def register_spot(request):
my_user = Stakeholder.objects.get(user=request.user)
form = SpotForm()
if request.method =='POST':
    print("print",request.POST)
    form = SpotForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)

context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'spotrequesting/register_spot.html', context)
```

When i submit the form i am getting an error in command prompt stating "This field is required" for "requestor". After that - dropdown list for this field come up on screen and i can select out of two registered users i have. But even selecting something from this list and again submitting the form is giving me the same error.

Checking "my_user" variable - it is showing me that i am logged in.

Is there a way to pass to "requestor" field currently logged in user?
I was able to get the form saved only by deleting "requestor" from "fields" in SpotForm (which gave me "None" in the end for this field in database) but that's not the desired outcome.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really passing the `stakeholder` instance to the `requestor` field in the form are you? So you will have to do:

```
form = SpotForm(requestor = my_user)
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks for indicating. I have passed it to '''form = SpotForm()''' and submitted the form. Unfortunately it gave me another error - '''__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requestor' '''

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace @maciej_j ?

Comment: is it because you initially removed `requestor` field from the `fields` in `SpotForm`  to make it work ?

Comment: I have solved the issue (maybe not in a proper way) by making the request.POST mutable and adding additional argument there `request.POST['requestor'] = my_p.pk`